# spctl: command not found

Tags: terminal, bash

I recently upgraded to MacOS Catalina, on a 13-in, 2019 MacBook Pro.

I am installing some software, and the OS was complaining that it is not from a verified provider, so I decided to bypass it using:

```
sudo spctl --master-disable
```

However, I only got:

```
-bash: spctl: command not found
```

Here is my `~/.bash_profile`

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
export PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$HOME/.local/bin/
export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Any ideas how to fix it? `spctl` is a default function, so I guess I deleted something.

Comment: You current path is: `/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:::/Users/your_user_name/.local/bin/:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/`. The triple colon (only one is necessary!) is a result of `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:` (which doesn't make much sense!)

Comment: Just to explain the LD_LIBRARY thing: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:` results in `:`  for LD_LIBRARY_PATH if the value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH was undefined/empty previously or `VALUE:` if LD_LIBRARY_PATH was VALUE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ type spctl
spctl is /usr/sbin/spctl
```

So make sure to add `/usr/sbin` (and `/sbin`) to your `PATH`.

Usually this is done automatically in `/etc/profile` which takes all the paths listed in `/etc/paths`. As has been pointed out in the comments, you override this by setting the PATH to LD_LIBRARY_PATH in line 2 of your `.bash_profile`. If you fix this, you won't need line 3 (nor probably line 4) any longer.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept the answer in about ~6 mins. Are there any other standard paths that I am missing from my PATH?

Comment: @John See updated answer.